# The last steps of each epochs take too long time

Tags: deep-learning, keras

I'm using Keras. When I run `model.fit_generator(...)`, it goes 1 step per about 1.5 second, but the last step takes a few minutes.

```
Epoch 1/50
30/31 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.0676 - acc: 0.2010
```

Why?

Comment: Please include your full mode.fit_generator call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because you are giving validation data to Keras, through a parameter in `model.fit` or `model.fit_generator`.

After each epoch, Keras takes the validation data and evaluates the model on this data, which implies one forward pass for each validation data point, which might take a lot of time and might seem that Keras is stuck, but it is necessary when training a model.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue while training a CNN , and found that decreasing the image dimensions speeds up the training. The processing time is reduced due to reduced input dimension during both forward pass and backpropagation (while updating weights). If for example, you are using a CNN for image classification, image size of 64*64 would be processed much faster than of size 256*256, though obviously at the cost of losing out information due to lower resolution.